How to run 2 systemd units so that whenever the master starts, the slave stops, and if the mater stops, the slave starts
I have 2 units. Let's call them master and slave.
I want the slave unit to start whenever the master is stopped.
I want the slave unit to stop whenever the master is started.
The slave is not stopped/started manually.
Starting and stopping the slave must be as reliable as possible.
Solutions that do not work:



master::ExecStopPost:
systemctl start slave

master::ExecStartPre:
systemctl stop slave

Nominally it works, but I need a TimeoutStopSec on master. If the slave has a slow start starting up, maybe a long I/O wait, whatever, it may hit the timeout of the master, and the whole operation is killed. If possible, I want to avoid this whole "guessing the correct timeout" game.




master::Conflicts=slave.service
master::OnSuccess=slave.service
master::OnFailure=slave.service

So if the master stop for whatever reason, the slave is started, the 2 of them are as independent, as it gets.
However, this does not work. I need master to restart on error (Restart=on-failure), but testing this situation shows that systemd is buggy. With these settings, when master restartes after an error after RestartSec, slave is started, as well... Even worse, when master stops with an error after it was auto-restarted, the slave is stopped along with it...
So instead of running either master or slave, they are started and stopped together...
If I add slave::Conflicts=master.service I actually get the correct behavior, while master auto-restarts, slave is not started, when master hits StartLimitBurst, then slave is started.
But with the buggy behavior observed, I have zero confidence of using this solution.
Tested with:
systemd 252 (252.30-1~deb12u2)

For reference, in case I have overlooked something important, here are the tests I made:
(the identical files are not repeated)
master.service:
[Unit]
Description=Master
# !!!
Conflicts=slave.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=1000
StartLimitBurst=4
# !!!
OnSuccess=slave.service
# !!!
#OnFailure=slave.service
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/
StandardOutput=append:%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/master.log
StandardError=append:%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/master.log
SyslogIdentifier=master:
ExecStartPre=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_pre.sh
ExecStart=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master.sh
ExecStartPost=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_post.sh
ExecStop=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop.sh
ExecStopPost=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh
SendSIGKILL=yes
FinalKillSignal=SIGKILL
# !!!
Restart=on-failure
# !!!
RestartSec=5
RemainAfterExit=no

slave.service:
[Unit]
# !!!
#Conflicts=slave.service
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/
StandardOutput=append:%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/slave.log
StandardError=append:%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/slave.log
SyslogIdentifier=test_onsuccess:
ExecStartPre=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_pre.sh
ExecStart=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave.sh
ExecStartPost=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_post.sh
ExecStop=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop.sh
ExecStopPost=%h/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop_post.sh
SendSIGKILL=yes
FinalKillSignal=SIGKILL
RestartSec=20
RemainAfterExit=no

master_post.sh:
#!/bin/bash

echo "`date`: $0"

# only for TESTING
sleep 0.1   # give time to ExecStart= to finish printing its message
exit -1

master_stop_post.sh:
#!/bin/bash

echo "`date`: $0"

sleep 4
echo "`date`: $0: END"

master.sh:
slave.sh:
#!/bin/bash

echo "`date`: $0: START"
sleep 10
echo "`date`: $0: STOP"

master_pre.sh:
master_stop.sh:
slave_pre.sh:
slave_post.sh:
slave_stop.sh:
slave_stop_stop.sh:
#!/bin/bash

echo "`date`: $0"

Here are the results I got. Notice that the master and slave are started and stopped together:
master.log:
Sat Sep 14 07:57:11 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:11 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:11 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:11 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:15 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh: END
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:24 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh: END
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:34 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh: END
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:43 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/master_stop_post.sh: END

slave.log:
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:20 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:25 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:25 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:30 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:34 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:34 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_pre.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave.sh: START
Sat Sep 14 07:57:39 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_post.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:43 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop.sh
Sat Sep 14 07:57:43 PM CEST 2024: ~/prg/systemd/conflict_onsuccess/sh/slave_stop_post.sh

There are various behaviors based on what is enabled in the service files (Conflicts, OnSuccess, OnFailure), but most of that does not seem right.
I wonder if I maybe misunderstood these options, or these are never meant to be used together. But actually everything works as I expect if Restart=no, so I guess this is a bug.
EDIT:
I am not interested in a completely different solution, this is why I did not add details of the original problem I want to solve.
I only want to know if there is a versatile solution to the exact problem of starting a unit_2 when unit_1 is stopped and stopping unit2 when unit_1 is started.

In the comments, there was a suggestion of using a third unit to control the start and stop of the other 2.
For me, the problem with this is that it relies on custom code, making the use of systemd redundant. As much as possible, I want to rely on systemd mechanisms, which I don't have to code.

I think you are doing this at the wrong design level, where it's difficult. Have a single service that runs constantly, and does the master/slave scheduling internally.

@waltinator I do not want that - if I can avoid -, since it removes the event-based control between master/slave (at least on my level), and replaces with polling (poll master active, else start slave). And then there is the added complexity of finding a good poll resolution and a implementing a whole external solution. I want slave to be a kind of watchdog, enabling more escalation levels than a simple restart/reboot. This is why I want to rely on stock solutions (which may not be the most well-tested in this case, as it turns out).

That explanation doesn't really make sense. Is systemd somehow special that it can implement an event-based system? No, it is not – any program can use one of several (probably well over a dozen) ways to implement event-based control without the need for a poll timer. Given that systemd is only able to detect a service completely exiting (and not merely "inactivity"), you could also achieve that by monitoring a local socket (D-Bus does that), or by monitoring one end of a pipe (logind does that), or by reacting to SIGCHLD (...systemd does that), or by using flock(), or mutexes, and so on.

@u1686_grawity I have used almost all of the solutions You have proposed myself. I have not used systemd, and want to know more about the usage of systemd specifically.
